# Числа вставляются в колонку только, когда идут по возрастанию

Tags: mysql

Есть колонка `user_phone` (`INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`).

Когда вставляю 1234567890 нормально записывается, а когда 9876543210, то выдает `Uncaught Exception: Out of range value for column 'user_phone'`.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что в скорее всего используете 32 разрядный `INT`, а он равен = `2147483647`.
В основном используют `varchar` для таких целей, ну или как вариант использовать 64 разрядный = `9223372036854775807`.